# MySQL str_to_date conversion for selected format

Tags: mysql, datetime, formatting, type-conversion, str-to-date

Date conversion issue via `STR_TO_DATE` function in `MySQL`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('17-JUL-14','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

It shows as

```
 NULL
```

How can I show it as:

```
 2014-07-17 00:00:00
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `STR_TO_DATE`. You're feeding it 3 inputs, and saying insert into these 6 fields. First insert into the 3 appropriate inputs, then use `DATE_FORMAT` to get 0 for the additional fields.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('17-JUL-14','%d-%b-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') from dual;
```

Also you're going to want to use `%H`, as the lower case will auto value with 12 instead of 0.

Comment: Got it working with below format: `STR_TO_DATE('17-JUL-14','%d-%M-%Y %h:%i:%s')`

Comment: That results in July, 17 2014 00:00:00+0000, not the stated desire of 2014-07-17 00:00:00.

Answer (score 1):

Here is output:

```
 2014-07-17 00:00:00
```

Using:

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('17-JUL-14','%d-%M-%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Already Answered above, but since I saw this,

what you are doing is

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('17-JUL-14','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Which means you are putting 17 into Year (map 1st to 1st value), accidentally month still gets the correct value, but the day gets 14 again. well that is wrong.

Why you are not getting the output at all, %Y, %M and %D uses capital letters.